# Capture email smtp error with print_debugger without attachment dump

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

**Scenario:** I have a number of Codeigniter applications that I am improving the email delivery system to use a database queue. So my application logs all emails that need to be sent into the database. I run a cron job every minute to check this database queue and send out any pending emails (throttled to my server limits as needed).

It is all working fantastically and has dramatically improved our applications.

Part of the feature is it will record when emails are not sent, and will retry again later. As part of the process I update the database to include any error messages during the send attempts, for debugging later. I do this with $this->email->print_debugger().

Once again all working ok (normally).

**The problem** is if an attachment was included in the email, the attachment 'data' is dumped as part of the print_debugger() - so my database gets smashed with large text dumps of attachment data.

**What I tried:** So I went looking in the Email.php class of codeigniter, thinking I could extend the library to just not include the attachment data in the print_debugger() function - but it seems that the error that is returned from the function is actually from the SMTP server itself in another function. I cant see a way to stop the attachment data coming through on the error.

**Question/Challenge:** Can anyone see a way where I can capture an SMTP error, and the email headers - but not the attachment data? I'm happy to settle for not capturing any of the email body either (since I know what that is anyway in my database queue).

Comment: Anything which says "cron job which runs once a minute" makes me cringe.

Comment: why do you say that? its one request a minute - 60 an hour - thats nothing?

Comment: If you're on IMAP, use IDLE.  If you have email in local storage, use Procmail (or the local approximation, if you're not on a Unix-like platform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can just extend the library. This is the current function:

```
public function print_debugger()
{
    $msg = '';

    if (count($this->_debug_msg) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($this->_debug_msg as $val)
        {
            $msg .= $val;
        }
    }

    $msg .= "<pre>".$this->_header_str."\n".htmlspecialchars($this->_subject)."\n".htmlspecialchars($this->_finalbody).'</pre>';
    return $msg;
}
```

There are four main parts to what is returned:

- `_debug_msg` - The debug messages
- `_header_str` - The email's headers
- `_subject` - The email's subject
- `_finalbody` - The body of the message **and** the attachment data

Implementing a similar function, without `_finalbody` should give you the desired output but without the body and attachment data.

Here's an example solution, (with the class 'MY_Email' located here at: `application/libraries/MY_Email.php`):

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email
{
    public function my_print_debugger()
    {
        $msg = '';

        if (count($this->_debug_msg) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($this->_debug_msg as $val)
            {
                $msg .= $val;
            }
        }

        $msg .= "<pre>".$this->_header_str."\n".htmlspecialchars($this->_subject)."\n".'</pre>';
        return $msg;
    }
}
```

---

Looking through the code for the class, I think that `$_body` may contain the body data without the attachment data, so it could be worth trying to append `$this->_body`, rather than `$this->_finalbody` to the function. I've haven't tested this, so I'm not certain.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks - I tried that already - it turns out that the _debug_msg actually contains the error and the body text (with attachment data) - so it can't be split there

Comment: Hmm, that's odd - I've been playing about with it for a while now and I've looked through the library several times. It seems that line 1153: `$attachment[$z++] = chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($fp, $file)));`, in the email library, is what's responsible for adding the attachment data to `_finalbody`, which is dumped by `print_debugger`. I still think that overriding the `print_debugger` method and referencing `_body` instead of `_finalbody` ought to work. If you're sure that the attachment data is definitely in `_debug_msg`, then maybe you could post the debug messages? Thanks

Comment: For testing, it would be interesting if you could temporarily comment out line 1153 and see if you still get the attachment data dumped.

Comment: ok - I looked more - it seems _debug_msg is actually an array of strings. if I change the print_debugger to just use the first string, I get only the smtp error message, and I dont have to store all the headers, body, attachments etc - so thats perfect

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you've found a solution! I still find it odd that there isn't an option (a parameter or another function) that would exclude the attachment data, it seems really verbose and I wonder how many people have actually found that data useful! Maybe that's a change for a future release...

Comment: yeah - i've posted it on the github codeigniter page as a suggested feature